# install cinnamon on 17.04

Tags: ppa, cinnamon, 17.04

I want to test cinnamon on Ubuntu 17.04 so I created a VB and installed a clean ubuntu 17.04

Then I found instructions for [16.04](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/how-to-install-cinnamon-3-0-on-ubuntu):

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:embrosyn/cinnamon`
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cinnamon`

But the install gives an error:

```
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/embrosyn/cinnamon/ubuntu zesty/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Fetched 89,2 kB in 1s (63,7 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/embrosyn/cinnamon/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/embrosyn/cinnamon/ubuntu/dists/zesty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

there is a 404 on `http://ppa.launchpad.net/embrosyn/cinnamon/ubuntu/dists/zesty/main/binary-amd64/Packages`.

Is that the problem. And how do I fix it?

I just want too take cinnamon for a test drive in a virtual box on Ubuntu instead of mint.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem, that PPA goes up to 16.10 only. If we were talking about some software I would usually suggest to change "zesty" to "yakkety" but considering this is a complete desktop environment with lots of dependencies, I strongly advice against such trick.

Comment: *This PPA contains unofficial (though probably closest to official) builds of Cinnamon releases for the latest two long-term (LTS) and short-term (STS) support releases, which currently means:
-Ubuntu 16.04, Xenial Xerus (xenial),
-Ubuntu 16.10, Yakkety Yak (yakkety).*

Answer (score 6):

Cinnamon 3.2 is available from the universe repository - remember to enable this from *Software & Updates*. Then simply run

```
sudo apt install cinnamon-desktop-environment -y
```

Comment: there are any issues related on the installation of Cinnamon?

Comment: It result in broken packages here... :-/

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [Cinnamon nightly builds](https://launchpad.net/~gwendal-lebihan-dev/+archive/ubuntu/cinnamon-nightly). There's a zesty file.

Comment: Cinnamon always running in safe mode...

Answer (score 0):

The PPA is probably not ready for 17.04 so it doesn't include a file for 17.04. You need to wait so they can update it.

Comment: Don't give up. Install 17.04 on a virtual machine and figure out how to install one of the older cinnamon-desktop packages from ppa.launchpad.net/embrosyn  in 16.10. It's a matter of matching all of the cinnamon-desktop package's dependencies.

Comment: Do you have an alternative? I just want to install cinnamon

Answer (score 0):

Cinnamon is in the 17.04 repos, I'm typing from cinnamon 17.04 right now.

Open terminal with `Ctrl+Alt+T` and then type the following command to install it.

`sudo apt install cinnamon-desktop-environment -y`

then logoff and login to your new cinnamon de!